# Formatting date inside ArcGIS Online Indicator widget

Tags: arcgis-online, date, arcgis-survey123

In my data I have a field in "date" format. The data source is a survey123 layer.

I am not able to format the appearance to just year, month, day. In the widget the Time and pm or am is always shown.

Is there no way to format the date in the indicator widget?

Answer (score 2):

In the layer that powers the widget, change the display of the date field. In the Visualization option, select "Configure Pop-up", click "Configure Attributes", select the date field, and uncheck the "Show Time" option.

[image]

Comment: It seems this option is not available because the data source is a survey123 layer.